# Akka message order

Tags: java, scala, akka, actor

According to the Akka documentation ([Message Delivery Reliability - General Rules](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/general/message-delivery-reliability.html#the-general-rules)), the message order is preserved for a given sender-receiver pair. The `ActorRef.tell(Object msg, ActorRef sender)` method allows one to set another actor as the sender of the message. So my question is: 
Who is the sender in the sender-receiver pair, for which the order is preserved if the sender of the `ActorRef.tell` is not set to `self()` but to the ActorRef of another actor?

Which message order guarantees apply, if some code, which is not running in the context of an actor (e.g., interface thread), sends a message to an actor via `ActorRef.tell` and sets the sender to either `ActorRef.noSender()` or any other `ActorRef`?

Answer (score 1):

You could think of `sender` as sending thread, rather than sender `ActorRef`, so regardless of what you pass as sender `ActorRef` the messages will be place in the inbox in the order you called `tell` in that thread. Other threads doing `tell` could be sandwiched in any way with the `tell` calls of your thread, so this is what the `sender -> receiver` ordering guarantee refers to.